# Simple Add-on Development error: Nonetype object has no attribute, "getdatapointer" (Blender 3.0)

Tags: python, add-on

I'm having an error with a simple script that I've created as operator for an add-on in Blender 3.0. The script essentially does three things in the following order.

1st: it imports a smoke domain from a Blendfile defined inside the add-on

2nd: it creates a smoke flow object with a slightly distinct shape.

3rd: it keyframes the fuel amount in the smoke flow object four different on the timeline and makes them cyclic via the graph editor.

I'm getting the error "Nonetype object has no attribute, "getdatapointer"" whenever the line of code in the script that sets the next frame runs.

Here's a screenshot of the traceback error:
[image]

I've run this question by our other devs and they can't seem to see an issue. Any thoughts on this?

**I have a video explaining the issue in  detail here too:** https://youtu.be/OUFRnB7tiPY

**I've attached the simplified add-on file below if you want to run it.**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kYlhVOOrhNSXiTxe-cT_qoVBmt2HibD9/view?usp=sharing

Below is the actual code for the operator in the script(note that this won't work without being installed through the add-on as it will import things within the zipped add-on folder...so this is just for reference)

```
#My Smoke Plume operator preset
```

class WM_OT_BasicSmokePlumeOperator (bpy.types.Operator):
bl_idname = 'my.basicsmokeplume'
bl_label = 'Smoke Plume!'

```
def execute(self, context):
    khaos_tool = bpy.context.scene.khaos_tool
    #First lets add smoke domain for the Plume simulation
    #ADD SMOKE CUBE DOMAIN COMMANDS BELOW.
    #We APPEND a cube from our SOURCE BLEND FILE for our smoke domain ONLY IF THERE ISN"T one already.
    #The conditional if statement below checks to see if there is an object named 'Smoke Plume Domain' already inside the scene
    if bpy.data.objects.get('Smoke Plume Domain') == None:
            
            section = "\\Collection\\"
            objects = ["Smoke Plume Domain"] #name of group inside of blendfile directory
    
            directory = blend_file + section
    
            for obj in objects:
                filename = obj
                bpy.ops.wm.append(filename=filename, directory=directory)
                    
            #Now we use the command below to POSITION THE SMOKE DOMAIN TO THE 3D CURSER POSITION in the scene.    
            bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor(use_offset=False)
    
    #Now lets add our Smoke Plume flow object
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(radius=1, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(bpy.context.scene.cursor.location))
    #Now we rename our flow object to be called Smoke Plume emitter
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            obj.name = "Smoke Plume emitter"
    #enter edit mode to create more random shape for flow object
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    #in edit mode duplicate and move around new icosphere to more random shape
    bpy.ops.mesh.duplicate_move(MESH_OT_duplicate={"mode":1}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(-0.0558451, -0.893362, 0.507589), "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "mirror":False, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False})
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.772502, 0.772502, 0.772502), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.ops.mesh.duplicate_move(MESH_OT_duplicate={"mode":1}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0.353793, 0.540304, -1.02273), "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "mirror":False, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False})
    bpy.ops.mesh.duplicate_move(MESH_OT_duplicate={"mode":1}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0.0903818, 1.05114, 0.297613), "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "mirror":False, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False})
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(1.42968, 1.42968, 1.42968), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-0.0277951, -0.0762881, 0.0596367), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
    #toggle back to object mode so that we can make it a flow object with desired fuel settings and then add a domain cube later
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    #And now we scale the object down by 0.65 so its slightly smaller
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.5, 0.5, 0.35), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)

    
    #Now we continue below making the flow object we added above become a smoke/fire flow object with our desired flowsettings
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='FLUID')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].fluid_type = 'FLOW'
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.flow_type = 'FIRE'
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.flow_behavior = 'INFLOW'
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.flow_source = 'MESH'
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.use_initial_velocity = True
    #And below we set a keyframe for the fuel amount depending on the float value in the user input
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.fuel_amount = khaos_tool.highest_fuel_rate
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.fuel_amount')
    
    #Now we go forward in the timeline according to the Fuel Pulse timing frames the user has provided
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_current + khaos_tool.fuelpulsetiming)
    #Now we set the lowest fuel rate according to the user input
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.fuel_amount = khaos_tool.lowest_fuel_rate
    #And add a keyframe for that value below
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.fuel_amount')
    
    #Now we go forward in the timeline a SECOND TIME according to the Fuel Pulse timing frames the user has provided
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_current + khaos_tool.fuelpulsetiming)
    #Now we set the highest fuel rate according to the user input
    # bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.fuel_amount = self.highest_fuel_rate
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.fuel_amount = khaos_tool.highest_fuel_rate
    #And add a keyframe for that value below
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.fuel_amount')
    
    #Now we go forward in the timeline a THIRD time according to the Fuel Pulse timing frames the user has provided
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_current + khaos_tool.fuelpulsetiming)
    #Now we set the lowest fuel rate * 1.25 for some variation according to the user input
    # bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.fuel_amount = self.lowest_fuel_rate * 1.25
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.fuel_amount = khaos_tool.lowest_fuel_rate * 1.25
    #And add a keyframe for that value below
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.fuel_amount')
    
    #Now we go forward in the timeline a FOURTH TIME according to the Fuel Pulse timing frames the user has provided
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_current + khaos_tool.fuelpulsetiming)

    #Now we set the highest fuel rate according to the user input
    # bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.fuel_amount = self.highest_fuel_rate
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.fuel_amount = khaos_tool.highest_fuel_rate
    #And add a keyframe for that value below
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='modifiers["Fluid"].flow_settings.fuel_amount')
    
    #Now Change too graph editor so that we can make the keyframes cyclical
    bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'FCURVES'
    #make the wind strenght keyframes cyclical
    bpy.ops.graph.extrapolation_type(type='MAKE_CYCLIC')
    #go back to standard 3d viewport mode
    bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Anyways thanks so much for the help!

Comment: it would help if you could cut and past the text of the error traceback.  Sometimes the useful information is in the middle of the traceback.  Also at this point it's useful to know which version of Blender you're trying.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thanks Marty. Absolutely. I've updated the question text above with that information. Blender 3.0.

Comment: I don't have a solution but here is what I've noticed. You mentioned other devs not having an issue. I was only able to reproduce the exact error after disabling other addons. What is odd is that when I have another addon enabled (FLIP Fluids addon), I get _Returned a result with an error set_ with a traceback from the FLIP Fluids addon scripts. The traceback comes from _frame_change_post_ handlers as well as _frame_set_ operations within the addon. Since this script is causing side-effects in another addon, perhaps this may be a Python API bug or related to memory references in the script.

Comment: @RLGUY Thanks for looking at this.  That is really odd that using other add-ons created overlapping issues. You could be right about the API bug. I ended up fixing the bug simply by subtracting the "fuel Pulse timing variable" from frame 0 and setting the keyframes behind the timeline (Negative frames) rather than during the actual scene. Makes no sense to me but no bugs so far. 

Thanks again for the help! Really love this community!